# How to render and show some of the blog post in one page and rest of them to another page in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I made blog site using node js and mongodb . When i render blogs to other page all blogs show in one page. But i don't want to show all post in one page , I want to show 10 post in one page and other to the next page. I figured i can limit post using limit() method. But i can only limit and render them to only one page. But how can i render those to next page.
Example i have 20 post, I can render 10 post using limit (10) method to one page. But how can i render and show rest of 10 post to the next page. Please help me if anyone figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call skip on the cursor

see MongoDB documentation on [cursor skip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/) "This approach may be useful in implementing “paged” results".

This example is taken from Mongodb's [example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/)

```
function printStudents(pageNumber, nPerPage) {
  print( "Page: " + pageNumber );
  db.students.find()
             .skip( pageNumber > 0 ? ( ( pageNumber - 1 ) * nPerPage ) : 0 )
             .limit( nPerPage )
             .forEach( student => {
               print( student.name );
             } );
}
```